# Segmentation fault when trying to access data stored in vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to learn c++. I have created a vector class `vec` and I am trying to implement a method to compute the dot product.

It compiles fine but I get a segmentation error when running it. I have pinned the x(i) reference in the `dot` product method down as the cause, but I have no idea why. I gather it is something about accessing memory incorrectly, but I have no idea what I am doing incorrectly nor what the correct way would be.

My vector class:

```
class vec{

    private:
    vector<double> data;
    int n; // size

    public:
    vec (int s) { n = s; data.reserve(n); }

    double get(int i) { return data[i]; }
    void set(int i, double val) { data[i] = val; }
    int size() { return n; }

    double operator[] (int i) { return get(i); }
    double operator() (int i) { return get(i); }

    double dot (vec x) {
        assert(n == x.size());
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            z += data[i] * x(i);
        }

        return z;
    }

};
```

I am trying to use it like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    vec x = vec(3);
    x.set(0, 1);
    x.set(1, 1);
    x.set(2, 2);

    vec y = vec(3);
    y.set(0, 2);
    y.set(1, 2);
    y.set(2, 3);

    double z = x.dot(y);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
data.reserve(n);
```

To this:

```
data.resize(n);
```

The `reserve` does not create the items in a vector.  All it does is increase the capacity.  To actually create `n` objects up front, you use `resize`.

Also on a side note, I highly suggest you **not** use extraneous variables such as `n` to keep track of a vector's size.  Use the `vector::size()` function instead.  The reason is that you're risking bugs if for some reason `n` is not updated correctly.

Thus this should be your constructor:

```
vec (int s) : data(s) {}
```

and dump the `n` member variable.

Comment: That was fast. Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised this segfaulted, though. The memory is ready to use and there's no opportunity here for trying to read a trap representation from an uninitialised value, or anything like that. That's some dark magic. Possibly optimisations delaying (or entirely eliding) the allocation as the compiler sees that you never actually create any elements so the reserved memory "isn't needed".

Comment: I _know_ it's allowed to; I'm saying I'm surprised that it _did_.

Answer (score -2):

In this clause:

```
vec y = vec(3);
y.set(0, 2);
y.set(1, 2);
y.set(2, 3);
```

You're setting index 3, which is out of bounds of this vector. To fix it, either initialize `vec` to be of length `4`, or index somewhere else. :)

You should also be resizing instead of reserving, but getting this wrong shouldn't cause a segfault. It should just confuse people.

Comment: No, I am initializing index 2 to the value 3. Changing reserve to resize fixed it though.

Comment: Accessing an index that is only `reserve`d (part of the `capacity` but not of the `size`) is undefined behaviour, so you certainly _could_ cause a segfault, or anything else.